# Cauchy but not convergent sequence in $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Show that the $\arctan(nx)$ is Cauchy but not convergent in the $1$-norm of the space $C^1 [-1,1]$, where the standard $1$-norm is $||f||_1 = \int \limits _0^1 |f(x)| dx$

Comment: pleeeeeeeeeese help me

Comment: Good. You should also write in LaTeX (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and write where you have problems, what have you tried, and so on :-)

Comment: $arctan\left(nx\right)$ is pointwise convergent to what function, in what space is it (not)?
If it would be convergent to a function in $C^1$ with respect to the 1-Norm, what could you deduce about the function? would it coincide with the pointwise limit?

Comment: I do not think this is true: in the 1 norm I think the limit is the constant function $\pi/2$.

Comment: In other words, I think the constant $\pi/2$ is in $C^1$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 |\arctan(nx) - \pi/2| dx = 0$. The story would be different if the lower limit were negative...

Comment: max i don't undrestand what you want to say

Comment: the indication that i have that the limit in 0 is not continue

Comment: you acknowledge your question is wrongly formulated yet you don't care to fix it. Therefore it should be deleted.

Comment: @uniquesolution : A new user might not see where's the edit bottom is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Write $f_n(x) = \arctan (nx)$. Try to show that $\{f_n\}$ converge in $L^1$ norm to the function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \pi/2 &\text{if } x\in [0,1], \\-\pi/2 &\text{if } x\in [-1,0). \end{cases}$$

That is, try to show

$$ \int_{-1}^1 |f_n(x) - f(x)| dx \to 0$$

as $n\to \infty$. You might consider splitting the integral into $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$ part.

Comment: Strictly speaking, showing that it *does* converge in $L^1$ to a discontinuous function does not show that it *doesn't* converge in $L^1$ to some other continuous function. You must also show that there is no way to modify a function with a jump on a set of measure zero to make it continuous.

Comment: @Ian : Well, I hope the OP is aware of that. Indeed I except the OP to ask questions since the answer is not complete.